# Casting numeric string with leading currency symbol always becomes 0

Tags: php, casting, symbols, currency, text-parsing

I have this code and to `cast` a currency-prefixed number to an integer.

```
$t = "€2000";
$venc = (int)$t;
echo $venc; // actually echo is 0 and I want 2000 (remove symbol)
```

The output is `0` and not `2000`, so, the code is not working as I expect.

What is the reason for `(int)$t;` to not echo `2000`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

casting routine does not remove invalid characters, but start from the beginning and stops when first invalid character is reached then convert it to number, in your case Euro sign is invalid and it is the first character thus resulting number is 0.

check http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

you could try `(int)preg_replace('/\D/u','',$t);`

however if you are dealing with currencies you should not forget that they are not integers but floats (though using floats for currencies is not the best idea because of precision issues, i.e. 0.1 + 0.2 !== 0.3)

`(float)preg_replace('/[^0-9\.]/u','',$t);`

Comment: It makes no sense to declare the case-insensitive flag on this pattern -- there are no letters in the character class / pattern.

Answer (score 4):

This can help you

```
$t = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/i', '','€2000');
$venc = (int)$t;
echo $venc;
```

Comment: Way more elegant than my if/else/index_of/is_numeric method lol

Answer (score 0):

use [**substr**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
   echo substr($t,3);  // returns "2000"
```

Comment: strlen of euro sign is 3 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$t = "€2000";
$venc = (int)substr($t,1);
echo $venc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsing a string prefixed with the Euro currency symbol to an integer or float type value is cleanly done with `sscanf()` and will even handle negative values.

In the first parameter, hardcode the Euro symbol, then use `%d` to parse the following numeric substring as an integer or `%f` for a float value.  Other string functions do not offer the benefit of explicit type casting.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/O8bae))

```
$tests = [
    "€1000",
    "€66.66",
    "€-5.0005",
];

$result = [];
foreach ($tests as $t) {
    sscanf($t, '€%d', $result["$t: asInteger"]);
    sscanf($t, '€%f', $result["$t: asFloat"]);
}
var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(6) {
  ["€1000: asInteger"]=>
  int(1000)
  ["€1000: asFloat"]=>
  float(1000)
  ["€66.66: asInteger"]=>
  int(66)
  ["€66.66: asFloat"]=>
  float(66.66)
  ["€-5.0005: asInteger"]=>
  int(-5)
  ["€-5.0005: asFloat"]=>
  float(-5.0005)
}
```